# .NET Core MVC ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I've got a "Link" Model.

```
public class Link
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Project { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store the Project in another database table and link it to this model somehow and have the options in a dropdownlist.
I think I need to use a ViewModel but I am unsure what I need to do.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I guess I need to make a new model called "Project" and then create a ViewModel combining the two.

Do I then need to make a separate controller for the ViewModel or can I consume it within the "Link" Controller?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to store Project in another database? If yes, why? Is it a technical requirement? 
By the way, you should make a link between `Link` and `Project` with a foreign key. 
You could have a look at this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/. It might be useful for you.

Comment: Projects should be unique and stored in a separate table. When adding a new Link then the distinct Projects appear as a selection in a dropdown list.

Comment: You need to populate your dropdownlist with the records found in your "Project" table, do you have data access layer to do this? - Once you have this then store the ID of the project on the "Link" record in order to have a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to access the list of projects from Link class. And i believe you're using MVC. If that is what you want to do, you can do this with your Link class

```
public class Link
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project {get: set;}
}
```

and in you can define your project class as this

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

so now when you generate your controller class for Link you will get something like this

```
ViewBag.ProjectID = new SelectList(db.Projects, "ProjectID", "Name", list.ProjectID);
```

and your view will look something like this

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ProjectID ", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes this looks good, I'll give it a try. Just one question, everywhere seems to suggest that a ViewModel is good practice for this scenario, is that true?

Comment: Yes it is true. ViewModels allow you to shape multiple entities from one or more data models or sources into a single object, optimized for consumption and rendering by the view.  you can get a lot about it here : http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public class Link
{
    [Key]
    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    public string LinkName { get; set; }    
     public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Link> links { get; set; }
}
```

then just do mvc scaffolding Controllers and views for Both classes

Comment: This answer would also work but I gave the above post as the answer due to the ViewBag explanation. Thanks